# image view not being visible based on number of clicks

Tags: java

In my MainActiviy class I want to display image views of smiley faces based on the number of clicks that occur on the buttons jokes, poems and funnystories combined. However my switch statement does not seem to working as no images appear. Also if any of those image views become visible, then they should remain visible even after the user closing the app and reopening it.

I also notice a click count increasing by one when the user opens the app which is not correct. It should increase based on the buttons mentioned previously being clicked.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    SharedPreferencesManager prefManager = SharedPreferencesManager.getInstance(this);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button jokesButton = findViewById(R.id.button_jokes);
        Button poemsButton = findViewById(R.id.button_poems);
        Button funnyStoriesButton = findViewById(R.id.button_funny_stories);


        ImageView yellowSmileyFace = findViewById(R.id.yellow_happy);
        ImageView greenSmileyFace = findViewById(R.id.green_happy);
        ImageView redSmileyFace = findViewById(R.id.red_happy);


        jokesButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                prefManager.increaseClickCount();
                openContentPage("jokes");
            }
        });

        poemsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                prefManager.increaseClickCount();
                openContentPage("poems");
            }
        });

        funnyStoriesButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                prefManager.increaseClickCount();
                openContentPage("funnystories");
            }
        });

        TextView clickCountText = findViewById(R.id.click_count);
        clickCountText.setText(Integer.toString(prefManager.increaseClickCount()));


        switch (prefManager.increaseClickCount()){

            case 4 :
                yellowSmileyFace.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;
            case 8 :
                greenSmileyFace.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;
            case 12 :
                redSmileyFace.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;
            default :
                yellowSmileyFace.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                greenSmileyFace.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                redsmileyFace.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        }



    }

    private void openContentPage(String v) {
        Intent intentContentPage = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Content.class);
        intentContentPage.putExtra("keyPage", v);
        startActivity(intentContentPage);

    }


}
```

below is the Shared preferences class

```
public class SharedPreferencesManager {

    private static final String APP_PREFS = "AppPrefsFile";
    private static final String NUMBER_OF_CLICKS = "numberOfClicks";

    private SharedPreferences sharedPrefs;
    private static SharedPreferencesManager instance;



    private SharedPreferencesManager(Context context) {
        sharedPrefs = context.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(APP_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
    }


    public static synchronized SharedPreferencesManager getInstance(Context context){
        if(instance == null)
            instance = new SharedPreferencesManager(context);

        return instance;
    }

    public int increaseClickCount() {
        int clickCount = sharedPrefs.getInt(NUMBER_OF_CLICKS, 0);
        clickCount++;
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
        editor.putInt(NUMBER_OF_CLICKS, clickCount);
        editor.apply();
        return clickCount;
    }
}
```

Comment: It''s not homeork, it is my own app I am building.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a getter for your clicks

```
public int getClicks(){
    return sharedPrefs.getInt(NUMBER_OF_CLICKS, 0);
}
```

Whenever you want to get your clicks currently you are calling increaseClickCount() which causes your clicks to increment before returning them. That is why it gains clicks every time you open the stage and why your switch isn't working correctly

so add the above getter to your SharedPrefrenceManager and change these two lines

```
 switch (prefManager.increaseClickCount()){
```

to

```
 switch (prefManager.getClicks()){
```

---

```
clickCountText.setText(Integer.toString(prefManager.increaseClickCount()));
```

to

```
clickCountText.setText(Integer.toString(prefManager.getClicks()));
```

---

Tell me if that fixes your problem

Comment: perfect, thank you. I do have one little question if you don't mind answering. The click count, it only updats after I close the app and reopn it. For example if I am on 5 clicks and I press some buttons 5 more times, it will still display 5 clicks. However if I close the app and reopen, then it says number of clicks 10 times. Is there a way to make the click count increment at real time?

Comment: sorry for the slow response just add clickCountText.setText(Integer.toString(prefManager.getClicks())); under your click listeners

Answer (score 0):

The reason for counts' increase is you use `increaseClickCount()` to receive click count.You have to create another method to receive current clickCount. Your switch statement works only when they equal to 4,8 or 12. Maybe you should use `if` instead.

Answer (score 0):

> I also notice a click count increasing by one when the user opens the app which is not correct

It looks to me like this line of code, in MainActivity.onCreate() method will pass a text String of count 1 to clickCountText.

```
clickCountText.setText(Integer.toString(prefManager.increaseClickCount()));
```

Also, every time you call SharedPreferencesManager.increaseClickCount, you are assigning a value to `clickCount`, and whatever was there gets overwritten.

```
int clickCount = sharedPrefs.getInt(NUMBER_OF_CLICKS, 0);
```

What is that value?
System.out.println is your friend.
I use this pattern

```
System.out.println("MyClass, MyMethod, MyVariable:" + myVariable);
```

I always include the class and method because it can be annoying trying to figure out where println are coming from if you leave several in for debugging purposes and want to get rid of them later.